# Is there an Okubo-Weiss function for axisymmetric flows

Tags: fluid-dynamics, navier-stokes, vortex

I have recently learned about the Okubo-Weiss criterion in a ($x,y$) and a ($r,\theta$) coordinate system. Is it possible to recast this criterium in an ($z,r$) system, that is for axisymmetric cylindrical flows?